# SwiftUI TabView Rearrange Tab Order Preservation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview, uitabview

It looks like Apple's [TabView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) supports rearrangements automatically, but it quickly loses a rearrangement after you click on a tab.

Here's my playground code.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(self.arr, id: \.self) { name in
                Text("Tab \(name) content")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "\(name).square.fill")
                        Text(name)
                    }
            }
        }
        .font(.headline)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Here's the steps I go through in the gif.

1. I start on tab "1"
2. I go to the "more" tab and then click "edit"
3. I swap tab "2" with tab "3"
4. Close the rearrange screen
5. Then when I click tab "2" (which is now in position 3), the app resets the tabs back to their original order!

[image: Demo of issue]

I'm not sure if this is a SwiftUI bug or if there's a onRearrange hook I should have been listening to or what.

Comment: Theoretically `.onMove` should be working, as it is dynamic content, but it does not - tested on Xcode 11.2 ... it looks like feature uncompleted ))

Comment: I’m thinking so as well

Comment: As of XC 11.4.1, this misbehaviour it is still there. Is there an event to catch and possible to read  the new order so I can change the original order array?

Comment: Its 2022 and as of Xcode 14 Beta 5, this is still completely broken...

Comment: Does anybody know how to suppress the "Edit" button?  I'd rather not have users encounter this.

Comment: @BobJacobsen I believe there is a library out there to hook into UIKit views from SwiftUI. Maybe that would be a way to do it